# Does angular lazy loading compile everything, or when it is loaded

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

Apologies if this documented somewhere, but I couldn't find an answer.

We are trying to improve the loading time for our Angular application. Currently it takes 8seconds to load. About 3 to download all the resources and 5 to compile the app.

We can't use AOT right now due to some server side generation of html, but this is in scope for the future.

So, if we use lazy loading to only load modules when their routes are loaded, will we see a speed up in our compilation? IE does it compile the bare minimum, then compiles the modules being routed to just before navigation?

Comment: See https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-router-series-pillar-3-lazy-loading-aot-and-preloading-a23a046c51f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading won't improve your compilation time for the app, but will speed up the loading of client side pages.

With lazy loading only module required items are downloaded, so lightweight modules will be loaded faster, but if you have "heavy" modules they will take some time to be loaded.

Lazy loading is a good solution if it's a common case that your user only navigate few modules of your site, without the need to load all the resources the site require.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear. Does this mean that the compilation happens on only the components that have been loaded. And then further compilations occur when the next block is loaded?

Comment: All the code is compiled during app building, but the module code and all his assets are downloaded only on "user request", usually are this assets that slow down the page opening so basically with lazy loading you are demanding the assets retrieve only when the module is needed.

Comment: I see, so the assests (css, images etc) are done lazily, but the actual code compilation is done all at once on start up?

Comment: The code is compiled at runtime when required. I found this article https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-router-series-pillar-3-lazy-loading-aot-and-preloading-a23a046c51f0 that can give you a more complete view over how lazy loading work with different type of compilation, maybe can be an interesting reading